# Creating a Junit test for an object that will be made null

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to make a Junit test method that will check if a randomAccessFile variable is null based on what is set by OpenDB shown below. The two possible outcomes for this method are either the rStream (randomAccessFile) will either open the file specified by the user or throw an IO exception if the file doesn't exist leaving it null. I would like to leave the openDB method void if possible and code the test accordingly. Thanks.

```
public void openDB(){
        System.out.println("Name of your Database?\n");
        this.rStream = new RandomAccess(kb.nextLine(), "r", true);
    }
```

(The test as it stands currently. app.getrStream simply returns the rStream in question)

```
@Test
public void testOpenDB() 
{
    mainApp app = new mainApp();
    app.openDB();
    assertNull(app.getrStream());
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to write a test method that will pass over the exception if the inputted fileName doesn't exist.

Comment: This really isn't what unit tests are for. To start, they should not require user interactions. A unit test, by definition, should test a _isolated, self-contained_ unit of code. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/unit-testing/info

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assert the result when the `openDB` method fails, simply modify your test to use the expected attribute of the `@Test` annotation, like so:

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void testOpenDB() throws IOException {
    app.openDB();
}
```

No need to pry into the internal state of the application to check the null-ness of the stream.

Comment: The test still fails since it seems to be looking for an IOException even though our error is a FileNotFound exception. I have tried changing it to FileNotFoundException.class and throws FileNotFoundException accordingly, but I still do not get a true result. Would I be right in assuming that this is meant to return true or is it meant to return false?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`, so the test annotation should still work. Also, tests do not *return* true or false -- they pass or fail depending on the assertions you make. When you write a test like this, you assert that you expect a subclass of IOException to be thrown.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to say Pass/Fail. Should the expected result in this case be a pass or a fail because the test is Expecting an IOException?

Answer (score 1):

You can assert an `IOException` by annotating your test with

```
@Test(expected=IOException.class)
```

assuming your using JUnit 4.